# Is there a more concise way to read csv files in Python?

Tags: python, csv

```
with open(file, 'rb') as readerfile:
    reader = csv.reader(readerfile)
```

1. In the above syntax, can I perform the first and second line together? It seems unnecessary to use 2 variables ('readerfile' and 'reader' above) if I only need to use the latter.
2. Is the former variable ('readerfile') ever used?
3. Can I use the same variable name for both is that bad form?

Comment: Remember that `csv.reader` can operate on a large range of "file-like" objects.  It sounds like you want to bake your specific use (admittedly, the most common) into the reader itself.  That would make it less flexible.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that extra variables == extra overhead.  It's simply not, in any remotely measurable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file, 'rb'))
```

but that would mean you are not closing your file explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(file, 'rb') as readerfile:
```

The first line opens the file and stores the file object in `readerfile`.  The `with` statement ensures that the file is closed when you exit the block by any means, including exceptions.

```
    reader = csv.reader(readerfile)
```

The second line creates a CSV reader object using the file object.  It needs the file object (otherwise where would it read the data from?).  Of course you could conceivably store it in the same variable

```
    readerfile = csv.reader(readerfile)
```

if you wanted to (and don't plan on using the file object again), but this will likely lead to confusion for readers of your code.

*Note that you haven't read anything yet!*  You still need to *iterate over* the reader object in order to get the data that you're interested in, and if you close the file *before* that happens then the reader object won't work.  The file object is used behind the scenes by the reader object, even if you "hide" it by overwriting the `readerfile` variable.

Lastly, if you really want to do everything on one line, you could conceivably define a function that abstracts the `with` statement:

```
def with1(context, func):
    with context as x:
        return func(x)
```

Now you can write this as one line:

```
data = with1(open(file, 'rb'), lambda readerfile: list(csv.reader(readerfile)))
```

It's by no means clearer, however.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want a one-liner?

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file, 'rb'))
```

As said before, the problem with that is `with open()` allows you to do the following steps in one time:

1. Open the file
2. Do what you want with the file (inside your `open` block)
3. Close the file (that is implicit and you don't have to specify it)

If you don't use `with open` but directly `open`, you file stays opened until the object is garbage collected, and that could lead to unpredicted behaviour in some cases.

Plus, your original code (two lines) is **much more readable** than a one-liner.

Comment: `open` doesn't leave the file open forever; it closes when the file object gets garbage collected.  (of course I'm not advocating that usage, since Explicit Is Better Than Implicit)

Answer (score 1):

**This is not recommended at all**

Why is it important to use one line?

Most python programmers know well the benefits of using the *with* statement. Keep in mind that readers might be lazy (that is -read line by line-) on some cases. You want to be able to handle the file with the correct statement, ensuring the correct closing, even if errors arise.

Nevertheless, you can use a one liner for this, as stated in other answers:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put them together, then the file won't be closed automatically -- but that often doesn't really matter, since it will be closed automatically when the script terminates.

It's not common to need to reference the raw file once a`csv.reader`instance has been created from (except possibly to explicitly close it if you're not using a`with`statement).

If you use the same variable name for both, it will probably work because the`csv.reader`instance will still hold a reference to the file object, so it won't be garbage collected until the program ends. It's not a commonly idiom, however.

Since csv files are often processed sequentially, the following can be a fairly concise way to do it since the`csv.reader`instance frequently doesn't really need to be given a variable name and it will close the file properly even if an exception occurs:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as readerfile:
    for row in csv.reader(readerfile):
        process the data...
```